# find $(f^{-1})^{\prime} (\frac{ \sqrt 2 }{2})$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

let $f:\left[0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and    $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x} \max \{\sin t, \cos t\} d t$ .

> find $(f^{-1})^{\prime} (\frac{ \sqrt 2 }{2})$

we have $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x} \max \{\sin t, \cos t\} d t =\int_{0}^{x}  \cos t d t $ for $  0 \le x \le \frac{\pi}{4}$ and  $f(x)=\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{x}  \sin t d t$ for $ \frac{\pi}{4}  \le x \le \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: Do you mean $\frac d{dx}[ f^{-1}(x)]\bigg|_{x=2^{-\frac12}}=(f^{-1})’\left(\frac {\sqrt 2} 2\right)$ or what does the title’s notation mean?

Comment: @TymaGaidash .yes you right .

Comment: Your formula for $f(x)$ when $x>\pi/4$ is incorrect.

Comment: @TedShifrin . Why?

Comment: Because you need to add to it $\int_0^{\pi/4}\cos t\,dt$. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, the first thing to notice is that :

- if $0 \leq x \leq \displaystyle{\frac{\pi}{4}}$, then $\cos(x) > \sin(x)$, so
  $$f(x) = \int_0^x \cos(t) dt = \sin(x)$$
- if $ \displaystyle{\frac{\pi}{4} \leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}}$, then $\cos(x) \leq \sin(x)$, so
  $$f(x) = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \cos(t) dt + \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{x} \cos(t) dt  = \sqrt{2} - \cos(x)$$

It is easy to see that the function $f$ is strictly increasing and differentiable from $\displaystyle{\left[ 0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]}$ to $\displaystyle{\left[ 0, \sqrt{2}\right]}$, hence $f$ is a bijection and $f^{-1}$ is well-defined. Moreover, one has
$$f \left(\frac{\pi}{4} \right) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, \quad \quad \text{so } f^{-1} \left( \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right) = \frac{\pi}{4}.$$
Differentiating $f^{-1} \circ f = \text{Id}$, you get that $f'(x)  \left(f^{-1}\right)'(f(x)) = 1$ for every $x$. In particular, for $x =  \displaystyle{\frac{\pi}{4}}$, this gives
$$  \left(f^{-1}\right)'\left(  \displaystyle{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}\right) = \frac{1}{f' \left(  \displaystyle{\frac{\pi}{4}}\right)}$$

and because $f' \left(  \displaystyle{\frac{\pi}{4}}\right) = \cos \left(  \displaystyle{\frac{\pi}{4}}\right)  = \displaystyle{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}$, you get finally that $$ \boxed{ \left(f^{-1}\right)'\left(  \displaystyle{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}\right) = \sqrt{2}}$$